# MS Access, populate combobox based on text box entry

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an MS Access Form where users enter a store number.

Based on that entry, I have it set up so it auto-populates the region that store is in and some other information. I used IIf and Dlookup to accomplish this.

```
=IIf(([Store]>0),DLookUp("[Region]","[Store Listing]","[Store]= " & [Forms]![Project Details]![txtStore]),"")
```

I also have a table of vendors matched with stores. Each store has 2-3 vendors associated with it. I would like the vendors associated with a particular store to populate a combobox so the users can pick one.

Dlookup works but only for the first vendor that matches the store. It does not populate the rest of the list.

```
=DLookUp("[IP]","[Vendors]","[Store]= " & [Forms]![Project Details]![txtStore])
```

Is there an elegant way to populate the rest of the list in the combobox based on what store is entered?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John! It worked perfectly.

```
Private Sub txtStore_AfterUpdate()
combo0.RowSource = "Select IP from Vendors where (Store=" & [Forms]![Project Details]![txtStore] & ")"
combo0.Requery
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need this

```
Me.Combo0.RowSource = "Select IP from Vendors where Store=" & [Forms]![Project Details]![txtStore] & ")"
Me.Combo0.Requery
```

Dlookup returns only the 1st match...this is how it works

Comment: So I'm a noob here and may be doing this wrong. But I went to the Row source field under properties for that combobox. When I clicked there it opened a query editor. So I went to SQL view, entered the text above, saved it and nothing happened. With the following edits it displays a list of all vendors, not just those belonging to the store indicated. `SELECT Vendors.IP FROM Vendors WHERE ((("[Store]=" & [Forms]![Project Details]![txtStore] & "')")<>False));` What am I missing here? -Thanks again-

Comment: Ok ...in order for this code to work as you want you need to use VBA,..lets assume that you have a text box `txtStore` and a combo box `Combo0`...put the code on the After Update event of `txtStore` and you are done